# Two way data binding on table

Tags: angular, typescript

i dont know how to do a two way data binding in table between my .ts and my .html
I have a struture that add a new equipamento in the array, and i want that new equipament shows on the table in the same screen.

I think is something like a add a [(ngModel)] but i dont know

above is the code

```js
export class EquipamentosCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  equipamentos: EquipamentoUnico[] = [
    {nameSaida: 'teste1', portaSaida: 'teste2'}
  ];


  displayedColumns: string[] = ['nameSaida', 'portaSaida'];

  equipamentoUnico: EquipamentoUnico = {
    nameSaida: '',
    portaSaida: ''
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  addEquipamento(): void {
    this.equipamentos.push(this.equipamentoUnico);
    console.log(this.equipamentos);
    //console.log(equip);
  }

}
```

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>Cadastro Equipamento</mat-card-title>
    <form>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Nome Saida" [(ngModel)]="equipamentoUnico.nameSaida" name="nameSaida">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Porta Saida" [(ngModel)]="equipamentoUnico.portaSaida" name="portaSaida">
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="addEquipamento()" color="primary">+</button>
</mat-card>

<div class="mat-elevation-z4">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="equipamentos">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="nameSaida">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>nameSaida</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let equipamentos;">{{equipamentos.nameSaida}}</td>
          </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="portaSaida">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>portaSaida</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let equipamentos">{{equipamentos.portaSaida}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let equipamentos; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your AddEquipamento() method is wrong.*

**Solution code:**

```
export interface EquipamentoUnico {
  nameSaida: string;
  portaSaida: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: EquipamentoUnico[] = [
  { nameSaida: 'test1', portaSaida: 'teste2' }
];

export class EquipamentosCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['nameSaida', 'portaSaida'];

  equipamentoUnico: EquipamentoUnico = {
    nameSaida: '',
    portaSaida: ''
  }

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  addEquipamento() {
    ELEMENT_DATA.push(this.equipamentoUnico);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
    this.equipamentoUnico = {
    portaSaida: '',
    nameSaida: ''
  };
```

}}

**HTML you need to correct this lines:**

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">{{element.nameSaida}}</td>
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">{{element.portaSaida}}</td>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
```

Comment: thanks dude, i just change the table to local (ELEMENT_DATA) and works